# What's the behavior of psycopg2 cursor fetchmany

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am kind of confused about the behavior of psycopg2 cursor fetchmany method compared with paging query

Say, I have a query that will get 10000 rows in total.

When I use `fetchall`, I understand that the 10000 rows will be fetched back to the python process in one round.

But when I use fetchmany and the fetch size is 3000, then it will perform 4 times to get back all the 10000 rows (3000*3+1000),does the psycopg2 cursor will kick off 4 queries like the paging query does or only one query is performed but the db server is prepared for the data to be transferred in 4 rounds?

I want to use fetchmany, but I don't like the many rounds query.

Could some one help explain, thanks.

Comment: As I understand it, if you are using a client side cursor, all the results are retrieved from the server when `cursor.execute` (or equivalent) is called. The `fetch*` methods get results from the cursor on the client side.  If you want pagination could must either construct the appropriate queries on the client side or use a server-side cursor.

Comment: Per your explanation，it works the same as `fetchmany` from the view of the server-client communation......